# Why wont mysqli connect using mysqli_Connect?

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

Could someone please help me, i tried removing the (Object(mysqli)) but it gives me another error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_connect_errno() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\elitedating\assets\includes\connect.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\elitedating\assets\includes\connect.php(10): mysqli_connect_errno(Object(mysqli)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\elitedating\assets\includes\core.php(4): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\elitedating\index.php(15): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\elitedating\assets\includes\connect.php on line 10

Comment: from what that exception states, you are passing an argument although you should be passing no arguments.

Comment: @FCR But what do i remove? 

if( mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli) ) 
{
    exit( mysqli_connect_error() );
}

i tried removing "($mysqli)" which produced an error?

Comment: removing $mysqli from the function mysqli_connect_errno() shouldn't cause an error. You sure the error is coming from that line?

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to go on since there's no code provided, but looking at the error given, it seems you're passing an argument into `mysqli_connect_errno` in your `connect.php` file on line 10. `mysqli_connect_errno` doesn't take any arguments, it only returns the last error code from the last `mysqli_connect` call if any.

```php
$link = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
```

Source: [mysqli_connect_errno](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php).

Removing the argument you passed to `mysqli_connect_errno` should fix your issue.

Comment: Please help us close questions as duplicates. We really do not need multiple low-quality questions about the same error message. If you want you can add this answer to the previous question and delete it from here.